# why are metaclasses created in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I m trying to understand the Ruby Object Model. I understood that the instance methods are saved in the class rather than in the objects of the class because it removes redundancy. I read that whenever a class is created, a metaclass is created too for the newly created class. the metaclass stores the class methods. ie the singleton methods of the class are located in the metaclass. eg

```
class MyClass
  def hi
    'hi object'
  end

  def self.bye
    'bye singleton method'
  end
end
```

for the above MyClass, a metaclass (say #MyClass) is created too. now the method 'hi' is an instance level method and can be called on all the objects of MyClass. method 'bye' is a singleton method of MyClass and it resides in the #MyClass. the reason (i think so) why 'hi' is saved in MyClass rather than all the objects of MyClass is because it avoids redundancy. But we cant have more than one classes named MyClass. **So why not store 'bye' in MyClass rather than in #MyClass, since we cant have more than one MyClass.** I have absolutely no idea why this is the way it is and i m just trying to understand the reason behind it.

-----UPDATE----

metaclass store the class information like the singleton methods and other stuff. But since a class is a singleton object(its an instance of class Class and is alone of its type) then why not save all the information in the class itself rather than the metaclass.

Comment: What makes you think a metaclass is created?

Comment: ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_CLASS] increments the count by 2 when a new class is declared.

Comment: How do you determine the extra one is the meta class? Did you look at the source code or just assume the extra object is the meta class?

Comment: interesting article i just read regarding metaclasses - http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/html/seeingMetaclassesClearly.html

Comment: @texasbruce i m reading 'Ruby under a microscope'. Pat explains that metaclass is created but unfortunately he doesnt explain y it is created. also, 'Metaprogramming Ruby' says the same. you gotta read it because its interesting.

Comment: it needs to store the static methods *somewhere*...

Comment: @rogerdpack i agree with u. but then a class is singleton so y not store it in the class itself and avoid the overhead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just to be super duper clear.

Here is a quick ruby script that explains the question:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_CLASS] #>> 471
class X
  def self.foo
  end
  def bar
  end
end
puts ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_CLASS] #>> 473
```

This is what the OP meant by "ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_CLASS] increments the count by 2." Let's call the extra class the singleton class of X, because that appears to be what Ruby calls it internally.

```
irb> X
=> X
irb> X.singleton_class
=> <Class: X>
```

Notice that the `#foo` method is an instance method of `X.singleton_class`, not `X`.

```
irb> X.instance_methods(false)
=> [:baz]
irb> X.singleton_class.instance_methods(false)
=> [:foo]
```

So why is `:foo` stored in `X.singleton_class` instead of `X`? Isn't there only ever going to be one `X`?

I believe the main reason is for consistency. Consider the following, simpler scenario concerning plain instance objects.

```
car = Car.new
def car.go_forth_and_conquer
end
```

As @mikej explained superbly, this new method is stored in car's singleton class.

```
irb> car.singleton_class.instance_methods(false)
=> [:go_forth_and_conquer]
```

### Classes are Objects

Now, classes are objects too. Each class is an instance of `Class`. Thus, when a class (say, `X`) is defined, ruby is really creating an instance of `Class`, and then adding methods to the instance (similar to what we did to `car` above.) For example, here is an alternative way to create a new class

```
Car = Class.new do
  def go_forth_and_conquer
    puts "vroom"
  end
end
Car.new.go_forth_and_conquer
```

Therefore, it is much easier to just reuse the code and do it the same way (i.e. keep `foo` in `X.singleton_class`.) This probably requires less effort and will lead to fewer surprises, so no one will ever need to write code to handle `Class` instances differently from other instances.

### Probably Doesn't Matter

You might be thinking that if Ruby did not have singleton classes for instances of `Class`, there could be some memory savings. However, it sounds to me that where `bar` is actually stored is an implementation detail that we probably shouldn't count on. Rubinius, MRI, and JRuby could all store methods and instances differently, as long as the behavior is consistent. For all we know, there could be a reasonable implementation of Ruby that doesn't eagerly create singleton classes for class objects, for the exact same reasons you outlined, *as long as the overall behavior conforms to the ruby spec*. (E.g. an actual singleton class doesn't exist until the `#singleton_class` method is first invoked.)

Comment: I know this answer is old but I am using ruby 2.5.1 and it's creating three objects for me. Any reason for that?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't quite an answer to your question, but it might be useful. Two things to think about that might help:

- metaclass is not really a good name for what's going on here when you think of how the [meta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta) prefix is used in other scenarios. *eigenclass* which you will see used in other documentation is probably a better name, meaning "an object's own class"
- It's not just classes that have an eigenclass, every object does

The eigenclass is used to store methods that are specific to a particular object. e.g. we can add a method to a single String object:

```
my_string = 'Example'
def my_string.example_method
  puts "Just an example"
end
```

This method can only be called on `my_string` and not on any other String object. We can see that it is stored in `my_string`'s eigenclass:

```
eigenclass = class << my_string; self; end # get hold of my_string's eigenclass
eigenclass.instance_methods(false) # => [:example_method]
```

Remembering that classes are objects, in this context, it makes sense that the methods specific to a particular class should be stored in that class's eigenclass.

---

Update: actually, there is an eigenclass for the eigenclass. We can see this more easily if we add `eigenclass` as a method to Object:

```
class Object 
  def eigenclass 
    class << self
      self
    end 
  end 
end
```

and then we can do:

```
irb(main):049:0> my_string.eigenclass
=> #<Class:#<String:0x269ec98>>
irb(main):050:0> my_string.eigenclass.eigenclass
=> #<Class:#<Class:#<String:0x269ec98>>>
irb(main):051:0> my_string.eigenclass.eigenclass.eigenclass # etc!
=> #<Class:#<Class:#<Class:#<String:0x269ec98>>>>
```

whilst this seemingly creates an infinite regress, this is avoided because Ruby only creates the eigenclasses on as they are needed. I think the name "metaclass" really is a source of part your confusion because you are expecting a "metaclass" to hold some kind of information that it actually doesn't.

Comment: i agree that methods for an object can be declared. We are so used to the concept of Classes as templates and objects as actual instances that we forget that in ruby, classes too are objects. And its good approach to save the methods in 'classes' than in objects else it puts the overhead of adding it explicitly for every object of the class and its pure duplication.

Comment: but i m more confused on the approach of creating metaclass/eigenclass for every class just to store the class info. so where is a metaclass information stored? is there a metaclass for metaclass? i know its not there but i m just curious abt the approach.

Answer (score 2):

The reason really boils down to what `self` is. For any given method, `self` is an instance of the object that the method is defined one.

In an instance method, stored on `MyClass`, `self` will be the instance of `MyClass` that you called `#hi` from. In a class method, `self` will be the instance of the metaclass (that is, the class itself). Doing it with the metaclass means that the concept of `self` is unchanged, even when operating on a class, which is itself just a singleton instance of its metaclass.

Answer (score 2):

As per [The Ruby Programming Language](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516178.do)  the class methods, are infact singleton methods on an instance of the class that got same name as the class.

```
Class Foo
  def self.bar
    "Am a class method"
  end
end
```

here method `self.bar` can be depicted as a *singleton method* on an instance `Foo` of type `Class Foo`.

```
#the following code is just to explain on what actually are class methods called
Foo.bar #=> "Am a class method" 
#the call is done on an instance of class Foo which got ref name Foo
```

We can go on adding more class/singleton/metaclass methods on `Foo` by

```
class<<Foo
  def self.another_bar
    "Am another class method"
  end
end

Foo.another_bar #=>"Am another class method"
```

*More formally singleton methods are defined as instance methods of an anonymous eigenclass/meta class.*

Though conceptually wrong we can assume classes are objects in this context, so as to have a better grasp.

This concept is there to bring in true Object Oriented - ness in all levels of the language. Objective-C implements class methods in a similar fashion.

In Obj-C metaclasses bails out as classes which contain information about the classes it `meta`. And the principles of inheritance do apply for meta-classes as well, there super class is its classe's superclasse's metaclass and climbs up so until it reaches the base object, whoe's metaclass is the metaclass itself. More reading on this can be done [here](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html).