# Why does ruby create 3 objects after a class is created?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I was studying about Ruby's metaclass. I [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17712082/7903039) where it is nicely described what metaclass is. It's showed there when a class is created it will create two objects. Which is understandable. One for the class itself and one for it's metaclass. But when I am trying it myself I see that it is creating three objects.

```
puts "Before Class Creation object count - #{ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_CLASS]}"
class Test
  def self.foo # test_singleton
    p 'Printed from method #foo'
  end

  def bar # test
    p 'Printed from method #bar'
  end
end
puts "After Class Creation object count - #{ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_CLASS]}"

###############

Before Class Creation object count - 949
After Class Creation object count - 952
```

I am using `Ruby - 2.5.1`.

Can anyone help me understand this one?

**Update:**

The [reference SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17712082/7903039) post that I added is using ruby-1.9.1 or greater, as the method `count_objects` for `ObjectSpace` was introduced in 1.9.1. It seems that the `T_CLASS` count has always always been 3 (tried with `ruby-1.9.3-p551`).

So, till now it's still a mystery why [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17712082/7903039). [Ruby under a microscope](http://patshaughnessy.net/ruby-under-a-microscope) also says the count is 2.

Comment: When run at the command line the difference is `2`. When run with IRB the difference is `3`. IRB seems to be doing something on its own. Did you get your result using IRB? In any event, executing `ObjectSpace` methods run within IRB (and Pry, perhaps) give distorted results.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I was thinking in that direction, too, except when *I* run it on the command line, I get 3 as well. The only difference is the total I get. When in IRb, I get 1001 and 998 (and it's fairly consistent between runs), on the command line, I get significantly less, and when I use `--disable-jit --disable-gems --disable-did_you_mean`, I get even less, but the count is always consistent across runs and always differs by 3. I'm using YARV 2.7.1 from Homebrew on macOS "Catalina" 10.15.4.

Comment: @JörgWMittag and...

Comment: Last time I checked, YARV was eagerly *always* creating singleton classes for modules and classes as a performance optimization, under the assumption, that modules and classes will almost always have module functions and class methods. Cleary, according to @CarySwoveland's findings, that is no longer true. I really need to update my knowledge of YARV internals. (I've been much more interested in TruffleRuby and Rubinius the last couple of years and mostly doing ECMAScript the last three.) It's still a mystery where that third class is coming from.

Comment: ...Stefan and others, I misspoke. When I run `class Test; end` the difference in count is 2; when I run `class Test; def self.t; end; end` the difference is 3, seemingly because creating the class method creates `Test`'s singleton class. However, if I run `ObjectClass.each_object(Class)` before and after the difference in the arrays is `[Test]` in the first case and `[Test, #<Class:Test>]` in the second.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, my apologies, I messed up. My comment immediately above provides the correction, though it doesn't seem to bear on your last comment. I am using v2.6.3.

Comment: Seems like we will forever be in the darkness with the third object.

Comment: If *I* were the one who has to figure out how to implement `Module#prepend` efficiently, I would do it with an extra class created for each class. I have no idea whether YARV does this, but it is how I would do it. Unfortunately, the answer in the question you linked to does not specify which Ruby version, which implementation, and which version of which implementation is used. However, considering that `Module#prepend` was introduced in Ruby 2.0, which was released only a few months before the answer was written, there is a chance the author was using Ruby 1.9 or 1.8.

Comment: @JörgWMittag that's my guess to. The answer is from july 2013. And ruby-2.0 was released in february 2013. So it's fairly possible that he was using 1.9 or 1.8 then.

Comment: @JörgWMittag in ruby 1.9 the count is also 3, and in ruby 1.8 there is no `count_objects` method for `ObjectSpace`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16788:

> Creating a class automatically creates a singleton class (which is not accessible to the user). Referencing the singleton class of a class automatically creates a singleton class of that singleton class.  This is to keep consistency of the inheritance structure of metaclasses. Otherwise, class methods wouldn't inherit from the superclass's metaclass, which is necessary as the superclass's class methods should be available as the subclass's class methods.

Modifying the question code a bit:

```
$old_classes = []
def print_objects
  new_classes = []
  ObjectSpace.each_object(Class){|x| new_classes << x}
  puts "New classes: #{new_classes - $old_classes}" unless $old_classes.empty?
  puts "Counts: #{ ObjectSpace.count_objects[:T_CLASS] }"
  $old_classes = new_classes
end

print_objects

class Test
end
puts 'Test class created'
print_objects

class Test
  def self.foo
  end 
end
puts 'Test singleton class referenced'
print_objects
```

I get the following results:

```
Counts: 690
Test class created
New classes: [Test]
Counts: 692
Test singleton class referenced
New classes: [#<Class:Test>]
Counts: 693
```

I tried it with Ruby 2.6 and 2.0 both inside and outside a console (the numbers differ but the difference is the same) and @SajibHassan with 1.9.3 (version in which the method `count_objects` was introduced).
This means that the difference has always been 3 and that the first singleton class created is not accessible for the user.

The book [Ruby Under a Microscope](http://patshaughnessy.net/ruby-under-a-microscope) (written in 2012 after the release of Ruby 2.1) also describes the creation of only two metaclasses, which doesn't match the result we get.

Note that methods like  `Module#prepend` (introduced in Ruby 2.0), which was mentioned by @JörgWMittag in the comments as the possible reason for this extra class, use `T_ICLASS`. Check [the commit in which the method was introduced](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/8ddbbb33242f413845079b0274c28331cb4aa0f5) for details. I guess that `T_ICLASS` stands for internal class and consequently internal classes shouldn't be visible to the user (which makes sense). I am not sure though why some `T_CLASS` are accessible to the user and some others are not.

Comment: I have run this in ruby v1.9.3p551. but the result is the same count 3. The author must used >= 1.9.1 because of the method "count_objects" introduced in 1.9.1.

Comment: I thinking this may be a bug, I have reported: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16788

Comment: There's a reply on your bug report which says it is expected as the other object is for the singleton class of the singleton class. Can you please edit your answer with the reference. I don't have much time left to award the bounty.

Comment: Updated! Although I am still curious why two singleton classes are needed.

Comment: Yeah I am curious about that too. But it's for another time I guess. Thanks for answering and getting to the bottom of it.

Comment: @RafayetMonon More details have been added to the issue. Mistery solved! (I added to the answer as well)